# Port Ubuntu touch on MSM8916 - display overlay get wrong resolution

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting-ubuntu-touch

We try to porting Ubuntu touch on a new unsupported target.
We met some trouble on display, therefore we can't see any thing over panel even panel is functional(We could show something on panel by chip register R/W ).
From the log, we saw unsupported resolution(-2x1091958595) overlay is configured therefore mdss will not show it to panel.
Does any one familiar to Qualcomm platform or MIR/lightdm and know how to resolve it?

- Ubuntu touch version: `vivid-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz` (2015-04-29)
- Device: MSM8916
- Android codebase: 4.4.4

---

```
Jan  1 00:02:49 ubuntu-phablet powerd[763]: Transition to ACTIVE complete
Jan  1 00:02:49 ubuntu-phablet powerd[763]: libsuspend: release_wake_lock: powerd_power_request
Jan  1 00:02:49 ubuntu-phablet kernel: [   45.378652] mdss_mdp_overlay_pipe_setup: exceeded max mixer supported resolution -2x1091958595
Jan  1 00:02:50 ubuntu-phablet dbus[708]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Jan  1 00:02:50 ubuntu-phablet dbus[708]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Jan  1 00:02:50 ubuntu-phablet kernel: [   45.792587] mdss_mdp_overlay_pipe_setup: exceeded max mixer supported resolution -2x1091958595
```